# Swift Class for multiple targets can't compile when calling target-specific functions

Tags: swift

In order to not rewrite the same code for different targets, I have "Universal" classes that are accessible for all targets.

Now I'm facing a problem where I call an API that's available on one target but not on the other. I don't care about functionality for the other target, the problem is that the code does not build as I'm unable to specify that the code should only get called on the "supported" target.

```
    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func isTestDevice() -> Bool {
        #if canImport(UIKit)
        print("iPhone")
        print(UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString) //Cannot find 'UIDevice' in scope
        return true
        #endif
        return false
    }
```

How can I make this function "optional" in a way that on devices that support `UIDevice` it returns true but on other targets it returns false?

Comment: My targets are iOS and watchOS. UIDevice is only available in UIKit, UIKit is not available on watchOS. The actual method compares the device UUID to my devices for debug output in production builds.

Comment: @matt do you need more info? I simply want to check for device ID for iPhone, and if it's watchOS calling that function, return something else.

Answer (score 1):

Neither `@available(iOS 13.0, *)` nor `#if canImport` seem to check at compile time for some reason.

I got it working by doing

```
#if os(iOS)
    print(UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString)
#endif
```

then it does not try to compile for other platforms.

Comment: Don't rant about SO in an answer, please. Nothing bad happened; the question was not downvoted, closed, or even criticized. Legitimate concerns about maltreatment can be posted to meta.

Comment: Stack Exchange sites use crowd sourced evaluation. People can upvote, downvote, close vote. Questions can be closed and people can vote to reopen. Votes are just votes; one vote is one among many, and in the end an equilibrium of some sort is reached. One should not take things personally nor fixate on individual event, but be willing to trust the "wisdom of the crowd" and learn from what it says. One should keep in mind too that neither the site nor anyone using it is one's personal servant. Be prepared to converse in comments, to improve the question, etc. Be open and friendly. Relax. :)